# Can Conditional Expected Value be negative in normal distribution?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, variance, expected-value

So, the problem gives me this facts (for a Normal bivariate distribution X,Y)

$$Var(Y|X=x) = 5$$
$$E(Y|X=x) = 2 + x$$

It asks me to find $$E[Y^2|X=7]$$

I tried this: using the conditional variance 
$$Var[Y|X=x] = E[Y^2|X=x] + E[Y|X=x]^2 $$
So, 
$$ E[Y^2|X=x] = Var[Y|X=x] - E[Y|X=x]^2$$
$$ E[Y^2|X=x] = 5 - (2 + x)^2$$
Evaluating in X = 7,
$$ E[Y^2|X=7] = 5 - (9)^2$$
$$ E[Y^2|X=7] = -76$$

Am I wrong? where?

Comment: but $\mathsf{var}(Y) = E(Y^2) - E^2(Y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mistake you made: $Var(Z)=E[Z^2]-(E[Z])^2$ (and not with a $+$).

So, $E[Z^2]=Var(Z)+(E[Z])^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The second term in the second step has a plus sign.